# Where do custom nanorc files go?

Tags: homebrew, customization, nano

When I update nano using Homebrew, the `/usr/local/share/nano` directory is overwritten and all of my custom `.nanorc` files are removed.

Is there a place where custom user `.nanorc` files should go where they can be protected from updates?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can copy your custom syntax definition files such as `perl.nanorc` in a dedicated directory such as `~/nanorc` and then include each of them from the `.nanorc` with an include directive.

In the `sample.nanorc`, you can see:

```
## If you wish, you may put your syntax definitions in separate files.
## You can make use of such files as follows:
##
## include "/path/to/syntax_file.nanorc"
```

Comment: I have a `~/.nanorc` and that's what's being used. The question is where do the custom `.nanorc` files (e.g. of the form `.../perl.nanorc` go)?

Comment: Ok, I've modified my answer.

Comment: So they can basically go anywhere (there's no real recommendation or idiom about the location)?

Comment: In Debian, these files are stored in `/usr/share/nano`. But for homebrew, there is no real recommendation. You can choose any directory you want.

Comment: That's the issue: the place there're stored by Hombrew is wiped out (it's linked) when nano is updated.

Comment: If you place the syntax definition files somewhere in your home directory they won't be wiped out by homebrew. You just have to include them from your `~/.nanorc`.